# What happened to the Leadership Code of Conduct?

Tags: community, history-of-ubuntu

I'm trying to read and perhaps sign the Leadership Code of Conduct, but all I can find is this:

- [Ubuntu Code of Conduct v2.0](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/conduct)

Back when the Code was in version 1.1, I could access the ["regular" CoC 1.1](https://launchpad.net/codeofconduct/1.1) and the [Leadership CoC that went along with it](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LeadershipCodeofConduct).

The Code of Conduct is now on version 2. Where is the corresponding Leadership Code of Conduct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the [Ubuntu Code of Conduct v2.0](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/conduct), there is no longer a separate Leadership Code of Conduct. Instead, CoC 2.0 covers both.

> Over the past two cycles the Community Council has put in a great deal
>   of effort to merge the original Code of Conduct with the very
>   important Leadership Code of Conduct so that the document more clearly
>   communicates the guiding principals the community has. That work has
>   involved two in-person sessions; one at UDS-Q and one at UDS-R. It has
>   also involved two drafts being shared with the community in an effort
>   to seek feedback. Every effort was made to clear up ambigous language
>   or phrases that posed difficulty to translations.

— [Charles Profitt](https://launchpad.net/~cprofitt), "[CoC Version 2.0 has been released](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-news-team/2012-November/001684.html)" ([official mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-news-team/) for [Ubuntu News Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NewsTeam))

So now, the one CoC includes the expectations for leadership. And agreeing to CoC 2.0 corresponds to what was formerly achieved by agreeing both to CoC 1.1 and the Leadership CoC.

It **makes sense** that they are both collapsed into one as, after all, there are numerous opportunities for both participation and leadership in the Ubuntu community, most of which require no formal recognition (though some leadership positions are official, as always). CoC 2.0 makes this clear too:

> We all lead by example, in debate and in action. We encourage new
>   participants to feel empowered to lead, to take action, and to
>   experiment when they feel innovation could improve the project.
>   Leadership can be exercised by anyone simply by taking action, there
>   is no need to wait for recognition when the opportunity to lead
>   presents itself.

— [Ubuntu Code of Conduct v2.0](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/conduct)

Comment: This would be time to edit http://askubuntu.com/election/3?cb=1 accordingly.

Comment: @guntbert For the benefit of other readers, the meta question for this is: [Can we update the election page to reflect code of conduct changes?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5981/can-we-update-the-election-page-to-reflect-code-of-conduct-changes)